# Netlogo error while observer running mean

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to plot the mean of a variable which is possessed by some of my agents (turtles). However, when I click setup an error occurs: `error while observer running mean...`

This is my code: `plot mean [score] of turtles with [not document?]`
To summarize it, each turtle possesses two variables, `score` and `document?`. If the agent is not a document then use it in the mean calculation.

I created some working code under the assumption that the error was related to initialization. 
Work-around code: `if (ticks > 0) [plot mean [score] of turtles with [not document?]]`

However, I'm looking for a better solution, I think its possible to leave out the if and somehow initialize the score variable before the mean function is called. If someone has another way to solve this I'm open to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you clear ticks at the beginning of setup, `if (ticks > 0)` should always return false when run from setup. Are you sure the mean is working, or is it possible it's just never being run?

Comment: That was my workaround. Since my code throws the error on setup but works fine after that, all I did was use `if (ticks > 0)` to avoid it being run on setup.

Comment: The code works properly after setup, it just breaks on setup.

Comment: When are the scores defined? If they are defined in the "to go" procedure, wouldn't it be better to just remove the code from setup and only have it in the `to go` procedure?

Comment: Also, in case it wasn't clear, I believe the problem is you trying to take the mean of scores before initializing them. Since (I'm assuming) they're initialized during the first tick, the `if(ticks > 0)` only allows them to be accessed after initialazation.

Comment: I also think that is the issue, but I am actually initializing them in the setup function. I'm looking for a way to initialize them before the plot tries to use them so I can get rid of the `if(ticks >0)`

Comment: Don't call `reset-ticks` until the very end of your `setup` procedure, since that's what triggers plotting.